# Isolate the significance column from summary(aov()) in r

Tags: r, summary

How do I isolate the significance column in summary(aov()) taking the pre-installed data `warpbreaks` as an example...

```
> a<-summary(aov(breaks~wool*tension,data=warpbreaks))
> a
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
wool          1    451   450.7   3.765 0.058213 .  
tension       2   2034  1017.1   8.498 0.000693 ***
wool:tension  2   1003   501.4   4.189 0.021044 *  
Residuals    48   5745   119.7                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

> somefunction(a)[,6]

1     .  
2     ***
3     *
4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# Extract the p-values
pvals <- a[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]]

# Use the symnum function to produce the symbols
sigSymbols <- symnum(pvals, na = FALSE, 
                     cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), 
                     symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))
```

This returns a vector with an attribute:

```
> sigSymbols
[1] .   *** *      
attr(,"legend")
[1] 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

If you don't want the `legend` attribute, you can use the argument `legend = FALSE` in the `symnum` function.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find/think of a direct method, so I just created my own. I extract the final column of the data frame, i.e. `Pr(>F)`

```
p = a[[1]][,5]
```

knocked off the last value since that's blank:

```
p = p[-length(p)]
```

then worked out the coding:

```
stars = findInterval(p, c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1,))
codes = c("***" , "**","*", ".", " ")
codes[stars]
```

You can of course put this in a function if you want.

```
 get_stars = function(p) {
         stars = findInterval(p, c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1))
         codes = c("***" , "**","*", ".", " ")
         codes[stars]
     }
```

**Example**

```
R> p = c(0.0005, 0.005, 0.025, 0.075, 0.5)
R> get_stars(p)
[1] "***" "**"  "*"   "."   " "
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods for extracting the p value described above did not work for me because my model included an error term. I had success using the following:

```
test.summary <- summary(aov(dv ~ iv1 + Error(grouping.factor / iv1 ), data = df))
p <- test.summary[[2]][[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][1]
```

Adding `[1]` after `[["Pr(>F)"]]` extracts just the p value and not the *null* value after it.

Also, @csgillespie, your code includes an extra comma after the final element in the vector, so R is expecting an argument after the `0.1`:

```
stars = findInterval(p, c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1,))
```